# Помощь с .htaccess: yii2 + angular 7

Tags: yii2, .htaccess, angular

Мой нынешний .htaccess для yii2

```
        Options +FollowSymLinks
        IndexIgnore */*
        RewriteEngine on

        # Добавляем другой запрос /frontend/web/$1
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(frontend/web|backend/web|administrator)
        RewriteRule (.*) /frontend/web/$1

        # Если frontend запрос
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/frontend/web
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule . /frontend/web/index.php
```

Теперь я хочу перейти на angular7, но получать данные с api контроллера "[https://домен/api/](https://%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD/api/)"

Т.е. перенаправить всё, кроме !^api на index.html (и файлов), сохранив работоспособность yii2

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать все запросы кроме api и файлы перенаправлять на index.html
Что то типа:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/api$
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(css|gif|ico|jpg|js|png|swf|txt|svg|woff|ttf|eot)$
  RewriteRule . path/to/index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```